# Разграничения определяемого слова и приложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Как разграничить определяемое слово от приложения? Содержащееся сведения в справочниках либо размыта, либо протеворечива. Приведу примеры из справочников.

У Лопатина читаем.***Рядом стоящие имена собственные и нарицательные могут
выполнять разные функции в зависимости от выражаемого значения***
 Например, в
предложении

> Вошла его сестра Маша приложением является сестра; будучи
>   логически
>   выделенным, слово сестра может стать определяемым, и тогда собственное
>   имя Маша
>   приобретает функцию уточняющего приложения и обособляется: Вошла его сестра,
>   Маша.

Здесь все понятно( о наличии сестер слушатель может знать, но ему неизвестно о какой именно из них идет речь).

Если ориентироваться справочник Лопатина, выходит, что решение ставить
или не
ставить запятую зависит от автора.

Примечание. Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от
наличия отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей
интонации
при чтении. Ср.:

Один только казак, Максим Голодуха, вырвался дорогою из татарских рук (Г.);
Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу; Он сына
моего, Борьку, напомнил ***(есть только один брат, один сын; если бы было
несколько, то при выражении той же мысли собственное имя не следовало бы
обособлять);***


Вошла её сестра Мария; Сегодня я и друг мой Серёжа уезжаем на юг; Выступал
староста группы Коля Петров; По дороге нам встретился главный инженер
Жуков.

В учебнике "Курс русского языка. Синтаксис и пунктуация " Л.В. и
д.ф.н., проф.
Дементьева В.В. , приводятся такие примеры.

***мой друг, Серёжа, решил поступать в университет (поясняется, какой
именно
из друзей решил поступать в университет). – Мой друг Серёжа решил
поступать в
университет (такого пояснения в данном контексте нет, причем именно имя
собственное является в данном случае определяемым словом, а нарицательное –
приложением).***

> Этот пример более логично отражает правило, но он противоречит примеру из
>   справочника Розенталя.Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату,
>   Аркадию
>   Алексеевичу (есть только один брат, если бы было несколько, то при
>   выражении той
>   же мысли собственное имя не следовало бы обособлять);
>   
>   У Розенталя запятая ставится, потому что брат один, а в примере из
>   учебнике (о
>   которым я писала), получается, что запятая стоит, потому что друзей
>   много. 
>   
>   Если ориентироваться на пример справочника Розенталя ( у нее только один
>   брат,
>   если бы было несколько, то при выражении той же мысли собственное имя не
>   следовало бы обособлять), тогда в этом примере должна быть запятая. 
>   
>   
>   ***В белом плаще с кровавым подбоем, шаркающей кавалерийской походкой,
>   ранним утром
>   четырнадцатого числа весеннего месяца нисана в крытую колоннаду между двумя
>   крыльями дворца Ирода Великого вышел прокуратор Иудеи Понтий Пилат (М.).***

Кстати, последнее предложение уже звучало в вопросе на нашем сайте, только логичного ответа не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, дело не в том, у меня один друг (брат) или несколько, а в логическом ударении, которое желает поставить автор. Если важно, что я еду с другом, а имя друга второстепенно, то "еду с другом, Сережей", в противном случае — "еду с другом Сережей". И не важно, это мой единственный друг или нет.
*Прокуратор Иудеи Понтий Пилат*, ср: *Президент России Владимир Путин*.